# What a class declaration must satisfy in order to instantiate type parameter in constructor?

Tags: c#

I find the question which of the given class definitions will allow me to create such a constructor. After testing, only the "Test1" class doesn't throw any errors, but I wonder what it has to inherit from, or "T" must be assigned to be able to instantiate "T"

```
    class Test<T> : TestClass, ITest
    {
        public Test()
        {
            var t = new T();

        }
    }
    class Test1<T> where T : TestClass, new()
    {
        public Test1()
        {
            var t = new T();

        }
    }
    class Test2<T> where T : object
    {
        public Test2()
        {
            var t = new T();

        }
    }
    class TestClass
    {

    }
    interface ITest
    {

    }
```

And my question is the same as in the title: What a class declaration must satisfy in order to instantiate type parameter in constructor?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: If you are asking "how do I make `var t = new T();` work?" then the answer is "add `, new()`" like you did, and make sure the `T` has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @mjwills and this is only 1 way? I think there was a good second answer, without new(), but I don't remember exactly what that declaration looked like.

Comment: @mjwills It's 2021 now. FP is now widely adopted and well-understood, so parameterless ctors are starting to become a _code smell_. Instead I suggest the generic types' ctors accept a `Func<T>` factory delegate instead of using `new()`, which always felt like a crutch to me anyway.

Comment: "allow me to create such a constructor." - please explain what you mean by this. The term "create" is ambiguous and overloaded.

Comment: @Dai I mean I create a constructor with var t = new T (); will not throw an error. As in the "Test" class: Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

Comment: @Dai I am not sure why you are directing that comment to me. If you want a debate about a language feature, ask a new question. I was merely trying to help the OP, not make a metaphysical argument about whether it was a good idea or not.

Comment: `I think there was a good second answer, without new()` I suspect `Activator.CreateInstance` is what you are thinking of. Which is like `, new()` without seatbelts.

Answer (score 0):

This will not compile because constraining to `TestClass` does not ensure a parameterless constructor will be present, even though `TestClass` does have a parameterless constructor:

```
class Test<T> : TestClass, ITest
{
    public Test()
    {
        var t = new T();
    }
}
```

That is because a derived type could be used that defines a constructor with parameters:

```
class DerivedTestClass : TestClass
{
    public DerivedTestClass(SomeType something) { }
}

var test = new Test<DerivedTestClass>(); // How can Test construct a DerivedTestClass?
```

For this reason, the `new()` constraint is always required to be able to call `new T()`.

Comment: I meant more of another way, you can declare the class without new () to be able to create an instance of T. But at least I now understand why this declaration allows this.

Comment: You could always defer that responsibility to the caller by adding a constructor: `public Test(T t)`.